# Laravel determine the date from database if MONDAY-SUNDAY

Tags: mysql, laravel, chart.js

Good day gorgeous friends on the internet!

I have a query to get data from database per week. Now I can get a result as you can see in the picture below.

Query:

```
         return static::selectRaw('SUM(total) as total')
            ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) as total_orders')
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [now()->startOfWeek(), now()->endOfWeek()])
            ->whereNotIn('status', ['canceled', 'refunded'])
            ->selectRaw('EXTRACT(DAY FROM created_at) as day')
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('EXTRACT(DAY FROM created_at)'))
            ->orderby('day')
            ->get();
```

and in my controller

```
        return response()->json([
            'data' => Order::salesAnalytics(),
        ]);
```

**RESULT**

[image: **RESULT**]

> The problem is how can I show it to my chartjs like this see picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this array to determine the day name from day number

```
days_numbers = [
 0 => 'saturday',
 1 => 'sunday',
 2 => 'monday',
 3 => 'thuesday',
 4 => 'wednesday',
 5 => 'thursday',
 6 => 'friday',
];
```

you can use this for getting day index:

```
$day_index = fmod($day_number, 7);
```

Comment: if( fmod($day_number, 7) === 1 || fmod($day_number, 7) === 2) {
 echo 'The day is sunday or monday';
}

Comment: i mean if the date is monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday or sunday

Comment: Use this in php
days_numbers[fmod($day_number, 7)] 
Or this command in mysql 
MOD(day, 7)

Comment: use 
data: [{x:'2016-12-25', y:20}, {x:'2016-12-26', y:10}]
from this page:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html

Comment: Seeing as these day numbers are built into the rdbms, this seems faintly redundant.